# How to get unix timestamp of next Monday in Javascript + MomentJS

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, unix, momentjs

I have a Javascript application and I'm using MomentJS to deal with timestamps and dates. 
Because a requirement now I need to find out the unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) of the next Monday, given the current date. I couldn't find any solution online except for some code that does a lot of DIY date manipulation, converting back and forth between strings and timestamps, a complete mess

Do you know any neat way to get the unix timestamp of the next Monday in a reliable way? By Monday I mean the first second of it

Comment: "*I couldn't find any solution…*" [Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+get+next+Monday)

Comment: @RobG "except for..."  keep reading!!!!!!

Comment: There are some very straight forward solutions in the search results, including `moment().day(1 + 7)`. Ok, it can get simpler but not by much! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
moment.utc().isoWeekday(8).startOf('day').unix()
```

Unix timestamp of the first day of the next month:

```
moment.utc().add(1, 'month').startOf('month').unix()
```

Comment: seems to work thanks! awesome! do you know if exists some code for the first day of the next month too? I mean, same concept but time stime find out the timestamp of the first second of the next month

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini see edit